# Prove that all squares are congruent to $0,1,4,9 \pmod{16}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I prove this? I can't seem to find any proofs online, and I thought it might have to do with the fact that all $n$ are congruent to $0,1,2$ or $3 \pmod 4$, so maybe $n^2$ is congruent to $0,1,4,9 \pmod{16}$, but I think this is false.

Comment: One simple way is to find $1^2, ...,  (15)^2$ mod $16$

Comment: Another smarter way is to expand $(4n + I)^2$ for $I$ taking values 0 to 3.

Comment: A compromise is $(8n+k)^2$, $k=-3$ to $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k\in \mathbb{Z},m\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ such that $n = 4k+m$. Consider:

\begin{align}
n^2 &= (4k+m)^2 \\ &=16k^2 + 8km + m^2 \\ &\equiv m^2+8km \pmod{16}
\end{align}

If $2\mid km$, then $n^2\equiv m^2\pmod{16}$, that is $0,1,4$ or $9$.

If $2\nmid km$, then $m\in\{1,3\}$, that implies $m^2 = 1$ or $9$. In both cases you'll have $n^2\equiv m^2+8\pmod{16}$, resulting $9$ or $1$.

So any square will be $\equiv 0,1,4$ or $9 \pmod{16}$.

Comment: Why did the km disappear if 2 doesn't divide km?

Comment: @SimonZhu Because $8x$ is either $\equiv 0$ or $8 \pmod{16}$, for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, depending on its parity. If $2\nmid km$, then $8km\equiv 8\pmod{16}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $m\equiv a \pmod n$ then $m^2\equiv a^2 \pmod n$. Why?

> $m\equiv a \pmod n\implies n|m-a\implies m=nk+a $, for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> $\therefore  m^2=n^2k^2+2nka+a^2=n(nk^2+2ka)+a^2\implies m^2\equiv a^2 \pmod n.$

In fact, if $m\equiv a \pmod n$ then $m^x\equiv a^x \pmod n$ $\forall \space x\in \mathbb{N}$. You can prove this like the other one if you know binomial theorem.